# NativeScript NS Theme styling RadDataForm, how do I get the default iOS style?

Tags: ios, angular, telerik, nativescript

So yesterday my app suddenly restarted and all my RadDataForms are styled from some theme applied..

I simply want the RadDataForm to have the basic, default look: white background, black text, no styling.

If I remove @import "~@nativescript/theme/blue"; from my styles, the labels will have a grey color, and the editor will still have this weird underline...

Why is there even two underlines?

[image]